# react-native ios webview file uri

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, webview

how can I open a local html file with javascript references in react-native webview?

I added my file "test.html" into the root directory then I reference as

```
<WebView source={{uri:"file:///test.html"}}
        style={styles.webview} />
```

but it generates the following error:

```
Domain:NSUrlErrorDomain 
Error: -1100
Description: the requested URL was not found on this server
```

How can I include static html files with Javascript in react native webview for IOS?